# How to open a Pdf with vbscript in Chrome and search by having a # in the url

Tags: google-chrome, pdf, vbscript, acrobat

Good day,

I am trying to open a pdf url using vbscript. The pdf is on a local pc. I am using vbscript to open the url and using chrome. In my Url I use a #Search=Register this will make the pdf open and search for the first occurrence of Register.

My problem is it seems that my Url gets % encoded even my # gets encoded to %23 and then the chrome pdf preview is not working.

My vbscript code :

```
Dim strChrome
Dim WShellChrome
Dim strUrl

Set WShellChrome = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
strChrome = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
strUrl = "\\myserver/HelpDocumentation/Configuration - Company Configuration.pdf#Search=Register"

WShellChrome.Run chr(34) + strChrome + chr(34) & " " & chr(34) + strUrl + chr(34), 1, false
```

When I run this code it opens up Chrome with the following url:

```
file://myserver/HelpDocumentation/Configuration%20-%20Company%20Configuration.pdf%23Search=Register
```

Note the % url encoding that has occurred. The %20 is a **space** and the %23 is the **#**

The browser then cant find the pdf Url because the **#** was encoded to **%23**.
If I change the **%23** in the browser url to **#** it works and the pdf is displayed.

It seems like the %20 (space) is ok in the url but it does not like the %23(#).

I need the # in the url to open the pdf and search a specific string.

It also seems not to be the vbscript, if I copy the url :

```
\\myserver/HelpDocumentation/Configuration - Company Configuration.pdf#Search=Register
```

And paste it into my chrome url it auto converts the spaces to %20 and the # to %23 but the acrobat preview is not working due to the %23 that it thinks is part of the file name.

Hope I make sense please ask if you do not understand.

Comment: Use [escape](https://ss64.com/vb/escape.html)  to encode the strUrl : `strUrl = escape(strUrl)` and use that value

Comment: If you are defining a UNC path, at least use the correct notation - \\server\share\folder\folder\file.extension, Chrome might allow you to mix back and forward slashes but UNC paths should be backslashes \.

Comment: You could try passing the uri correctly encoded before hand and leave the `#` as is. So it would be something like (ignoring the first part of the uri) - `Configuration%20-%20Company%20Configuration.pdf#Search=Register`, that way Chrome realises it's already encoded and doesn't try a second encoding. There also no need for all that `Chr(34)` nonsense just use `strChrome = """C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"""` you can do the same with the uri just add `""` and the beginning and end of the string.

Comment: @flakes Thanks for your response I tried escape but it encoded all characters even the / and \ please check the updated post.

Comment: @Lankymart Thanks for your suggestions, I did implement it and saw I need to include a file: at the start of my url for the browser to not encode again. I also had to add space encoding. I have updated my post with my results please check if you agree and also create a solution post. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Renier that’s good to hear, instead of updating the question however, could you please leave the solution as an answer so the question is resolved? There is no issue with self answering a question and you can even accept it yourself after a day or so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**After replies I tried the following.**

Tried using `strUrl = escape(strUrl)` but this resulted the strUrl to be fully encoded even the / and \ slashes.

Then I started checking different Urls as suggested changing my / to \ slashes as well as encoding spaces. This was my result.

When I use the url withoud encodeing spaces like

```
"\\myserver\HelpDocumentation\Configuration - Company Configuration.pdf#Search=Register_"
```

in chrome it does not encode at all and at every space in the url it opens a new tab. - Not working.

When I use

```
"\\myserver\HelpDocumentation\Configuration%20-%20Company%20Configuration.pdf#Search=Register_"
```

in chrome it changes to : `file://myserver/HelpDocumentation/Configuration%2520-%2520Company%2520Configuration.pdf%23Search=Register_`
Then not working because of double encoding. So it adds a "file:" and also encodes the url again, spaces and # is encoded.

When I use

```
file:\\myserver\HelpDocumentation\Configuration%20-%20Company%20Configuration.pdf#Search=Register_
```

in chrome it stays  the same and in result it is working. So the "file:" appended at the start and encoding just the spaces in the url makes the difference.

I ended up with the following code. Note the strUrl is a input variable I just hardcoded for example. I also now check if its a pdf then add "file:" as the url can be a file or a report url. This code works.

```
Dim strChrome
Dim WShellChrome
Dim strUrl

Set WShellChrome = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
strChrome = """C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"""
strUrl = "\\myserver\HelpDocumentation\Configuration - Company Configuration.pdf#Search=Register_"

strUrl = Replace(strUrl, " ", "%20")

if(InStr(strUrl,".pdf")) Then
   strUrl = "file:" + strUrl
End If

WShellChrome.Run strChrome & " " & ""+strUrl+"" , 1, false
```